# Save Customer's custom attributes when order is placed using "sales_order_place_after" event in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to save some customer's custom attributes after Order is placed By checking order item.
So i am using ***'sales_order_place_after'*** event, But in Observer Class I could Not Save it See My Code :

```
  namespace MagentoPro\Customer\Observer;

  use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
  use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
  use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

  class SaveCompanySubscription implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
  {
      public function __construct(
          CustomerRepositoryInterface $customer,
          Product $product
      ) {
           $this->product = $product; 
           $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customer;    
      }

      public function execute(Observer $observer)
      {
           $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
           $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
           $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
           $itemCollection = $order->getAllItems();

           foreach($itemCollection as $item){

               $productId = $item->getProductId(); 
               $prod = $this->product->load($productId);

               $is_subscribed = 1;
               $subscirption_ends_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$prod->getData('package_validity')." days"));
               $subscription_type = $prod->getData('package_type');

               $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
               $customer->setCustomAttribute('is_subscribed_company', $is_subscribed);
               $customer->setCustomAttribute('subscription_ends_on', $subscription_ends_on);
               $customer->setCustomAttribute('subscription_type', $subscription_type);

               $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

           }

           return $this;

      }
  }
```

Comment: Try `setData` instead of the `setCustomAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer.
I used ***'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'*** event.
and my observer class is :

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Saving Customer Data After Order Has Been Placed
     * Event : MagentoPro\Customer\etc\events.xml
    **/

    namespace MagentoPro\Customer\Observer;

    use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

    class SaveCompanySubscription implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {
        protected $orderFactory;

        public function __construct(
            CustomerRepositoryInterface $customer,
            Product $product,
            Order $orderFactory
        ) {
             $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
             $this->product = $product; 
             $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customer;    
        }

        public function execute(Observer $observer)
        {
             $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
             $lastorderId = $orderIds[0];
             $order = $this->orderFactory->load($lastorderId);
             $customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
             $itemCollection = $order->getAllItems();

             foreach($itemCollection as $item){

                 $productId = $item->getProductId(); 
                 $prod = $this->product->load($productId);

                 $is_subscribed = 1;
                 $subscription_ends_on = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+".$prod->getData('package_validity')." days"));
                 $subscription_type = $prod->getData('package_type');

                 $customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
                 $customer->setCustomAttribute('is_subscribed_company', $is_subscribed);
                 $customer->setCustomAttribute('subscription_ends_on', $subscription_ends_on);
                 $customer->setCustomAttribute('subscription_type', $subscription_type);

                 $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($customer);

             }

             return $this;

        }
    }
```

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code to save custom customer attribute.

```
$customermodel = $objectManager->create ('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
$customerData = $customermodel->getDataModel();
$customerData->setId($order->getCustomerId());
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_price_limit', $customerPriceLimit - $quote->getSubtotal());
$customermodel->updateData($customerData);

$customerResource = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory')->create();
$customerResource->saveAttribute($customermodel, 'customer_price_limit');
```

Comment: Use of $objectmanager is not good and recommended. Please check? Our Answer should work. If any query?

Comment: I am using tthe below code and does not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You should try following event:

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

Now you can able to observe from backend order too.

And for paypal you need to use following one:

```
paypal_express_place_order_success
```

Get order information:

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
```

[For more](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php#L376)

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/196398/59400 : Is this is Correct What I am Doing Please Check and Comment . I need help for That. Is 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action' event is not fired Everytime when user Places an Order ??